# df_dict in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following code which gets all the value I need (based on new_keys) and pass it on to a list.

However, I am having trouble getting the following line and the corresponding values:

```
'sales': [{'date': '2020-08-07',
       'price': 85,
       'saleType': 'Salg'},
      {'date': '1996-05-12', 'price': 0, 'saleType': 'Ukendt'}]
```

How do I get the column headers (date, price, saletype) and the corresponding values to my list?

```
new_keys = ["currentEstateId","address","zipCode","propertyType"]
response = 
{"canGetVR":true,"userHasEvalReport":false,"isActive":false,"currentEstateId":null,"address":"ReersÃ¸vej 24","addressObj":{"street":"ReersÃ¸vej","number":"24","zipCode":4281},"zipCode":4281,"city":"GÃ¸rlev","coordinates":{"latitude":55.534958,"longitude":11.126505},"guid":"236893f9-6b85-4307-a99a-8d9065c5066c","propertyType":4,"sales":[{"date":"2020-08-03T00:00:00","price":3600000,"saleType":"Alm. frit salg"},{"date":"2016-08-23T00:00:00","price":0,"saleType":"Familieoverdragelse"},{"date":"1999-04-08T00:00:00","price":750000,"saleType":"Alm. frit salg"}],"previousListings":[{"id":1674948,"address":"ReersÃ¸vej 24, ReersÃ¸","lastSeen":"2020-08-04T01:49:02","price":3945000,"zipCode":4281,"city":"GÃ¸rlev"},{"id":729684,"address":"ReersÃ¸vej 24","lastSeen":"2012-08-18T04:53:16","price":2500000,"zipCode":4281,"city":"GÃ¸rlev"},{"id":210326,"address":"ReersÃ¸vej 24","lastSeen":"2008-03-27T01:56:31","price":4395000,"zipCode":4281,"city":"GÃ¸rlev"}]}
df_dict = {key: response[key] for key in new_keys}
df_dict
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict,index=[0])
df
```

Comment: What do you actually want and what is it that's not working? Your pandas dataframe `df` has exactly the four items that you defined `new_keys`.

Comment: Hi Davelditto. Yes is does. But how do I get the columns date, price and saletype as columns as well and the corresponding values?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure how you want to merge the dataframe because there are two items under sales. Just to extract that portion, you could simply do,

```
rows = []
data_row = response['sales']
for row in data_row:
    rows.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(df)
```

returns you,

```
         date  price saleType
0  2020-08-07     85     Salg
1  1996-05-12      0   Ukendt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want also the nested value in your dict, (which are encoded as list) you should flatten your dict, as such

```
import pandas as pd

new_keys = ["currentEstateId","address","zipCode","propertyType"]
response = {
   "canGetVR": True,
   "userHasEvalReport": False,
   "isActive": False,
   "currentEstateId": None,
   "address":"ReersÃ¸vej 24",
   "addressObj":{
      "street":"ReersÃ¸vej",
      "number":"24",
      "zipCode":4281
   },
   "zipCode":4281,
   "city":"GÃ¸rlev",
   "coordinates":{
      "latitude":55.534958,
      "longitude":11.126505
   },
   "guid":"236893f9-6b85-4307-a99a-8d9065c5066c",
   "propertyType":4,
   "sales":[
      {
         "date":"2020-08-03T00:00:00",
         "price":3600000,
         "saleType":"Alm. frit salg"
      },
      {
         "date":"2016-08-23T00:00:00",
         "price":0,
         "saleType":"Familieoverdragelse"
      },
      {
         "date":"1999-04-08T00:00:00",
         "price":750000,
         "saleType":"Alm. frit salg"
      }
   ],
   "previousListings":[
      {
         "id":1674948,
         "address":"ReersÃ¸vej 24, ReersÃ¸",
         "lastSeen":"2020-08-04T01:49:02",
         "price":3945000,
         "zipCode":4281,
         "city":"GÃ¸rlev"
      },
      {
         "id":729684,
         "address":"ReersÃ¸vej 24",
         "lastSeen":"2012-08-18T04:53:16",
         "price":2500000,
         "zipCode":4281,
         "city":"GÃ¸rlev"
      },
      {
         "id":210326,
         "address":"ReersÃ¸vej 24",
         "lastSeen":"2008-03-27T01:56:31",
         "price":4395000,
         "zipCode":4281,
         "city":"GÃ¸rlev"
      }
   ]
}

sales = response["sales"]
coordinates = response["coordinates"]
dicts = []
for sale in sales:
    curr_dict = {key: response[key] for key in new_keys}
    curr_dict["latitude"] = coordinates["latitude"]
    curr_dict["longitude"] = coordinates["longitude"]
    for key in sale.keys():
        curr_dict[key] = sale[key]
    print(curr_dict)
    dicts.append(curr_dict)


df = pd.DataFrame(dicts)
print(df)
```

basically I have generated a new dict for every dict in your list `"sales"`, flattening the json structure

```
  currentEstateId        address  zipCode  propertyType   latitude  longitude                 date    price             saleType
0            None  ReersÃ¸vej 24     4281             4  55.534958  11.126505  2020-08-03T00:00:00  3600000       Alm. frit salg
1            None  ReersÃ¸vej 24     4281             4  55.534958  11.126505  2016-08-23T00:00:00        0  Familieoverdragelse
2            None  ReersÃ¸vej 24     4281             4  55.534958  11.126505  1999-04-08T00:00:00   750000       Alm. frit salg
```

Comment: Hi Nikaido. Thank you very much. It works just fine. Can you help me if I have the following element as well? coordinates":{"latitude":55.534958,"longitude":11.126505}. How can I get these two values out in two columns?

Comment: @Jeweller89 can you update the total json structure in the main question?

Comment: @Jeweller89 without knowing the exact structure and position of your new fields it's quite difficult do modify the code

Comment: Of course. Just updated the post. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Jeweller89 done :). Don't forget to accept the best answer to your question :)